# Doesnt have parent or Parent Class isnt found

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I have a method `findParentByClassName` which looks upwards for a specific parent class . It worked well but now I'm trying to return two alerts depending if 1) a `parentClass` of that name is not found. 2) it doesnt have a parent. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
var findParentByClassName = function(element, targetClass) {
    if (element.parentElement) {
        var currentParent = element.parentElement;
        while (currentParent.className != targetClass && currentParent.className !== null) {
            currentParent = currentParent.parentElement;
        }
        if (currentParent === targetClass) ? return currentParent : alert("No parent found with that class name");
    } else {
        alert("No Parent Element")
    }
};
```

Comment: you have any errors in the developer tools console? - like `expected expression, got '?'`

Comment: aside from having a syntax error, your function shouldn't return values and alert at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would replace alerts with exceptions or return undefined/null, and use the classList property.

But here is your code converted to working.

Your problem was the invalid use of the tenery, and you were not also checking if currentParent is null.

I've updated and added a `findParentByClassName2` that can handle parents with multiple classes, and return undefined if not found.

```js
var findParentByClassName = function(element, targetClass) {
    if (element.parentElement) {
        var currentParent = element.parentElement;
        while (currentParent && currentParent.className != targetClass && currentParent.className !== null) {
            currentParent = currentParent.parentElement;
        }
        if (currentParent && (currentParent.className === targetClass)) return currentParent;
        alert("No parent found with that class name");
    } else {
        alert("No Parent Element")
    }
};

//a modified version, that will also look for parents
//with multiple classes,.. 
var findParentByClassName2 = function(element, targetClass) {
  element = element ? element.parentElement : null; //skip self
  while (element) {      
    if (element.classList.contains(targetClass)) return element;
    element = element.parentElement;
  }  
}

var a = document.querySelector('.two');
console.log(findParentByClassName(a, 'one'));
console.log(findParentByClassName(a, 'invalid'));
console.log(findParentByClassName2(a, 'one'));
console.log(findParentByClassName2(a, 'invalid'));
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```